# Eclipse no reproduce el clip de audio

Tags: java, wav, javasound

Estoy intentado reproducir un sonido wav en eclipse y aunque el código se ejecuta correctamente, y aparece el mensaje final no se escucha sonido alguno.

Es la primera vez que implemento este tipo de métodos y creo que la ruta al fichero es correcta pero he estado viendo errores relacionados con el `InputStream`, en concreto con el método `getResourceAsStream`, en este caso no he utilizado ese método sino el método `getAudioInputStream  y aún así no se escucha sonido alguno.

¿Hay algo que este pasando por alto?

```
package sonido;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
public class TestSonido {


   // Abre un fichero de sonido wav y lo reproduce

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // Se obtiene un Clip de sonido
            Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();

            // Se carga con un fichero wav
            sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\adric\\Desktop\\ejemplo.wav")));

            // Comienza la reproducción
            sonido.start();

            // Espera mientras se esté reproduciendo.
            while (sonido.isRunning())
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Se cierra el clip.
            sonido.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("FIN");
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: El "mensaje final" aparecerá aunque haya habido una excepción al ejecutar el código, ya que te "comes" cualquier excepción que salga. ¿Sale algún mensaje de error por la excepción?

Comment: No, aún quitando esa linea de código se ejecuta correctamente, sin arrojar ningún tipo de error.

Comment: Suponiendo que la ruta al archivo .wav es correcta, el problema debe ser el while. @AdrianCerrosSanchez

Comment: ¿No funcionó eliminando el while ? @AdrianCerrosSanchez

Comment: No, pero no tengo del todo claro si el problema es de el propio Eclipse, sigue sin lanzar ningún error. Aún así gracias.

Comment: No va a lanzar un error, en ocasiones esta linea  while (sonido.isRunning())  provocarà que no funcione la reproducciòn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo como utilidad, una clase que hice para reproducir audios en `eclipse`, concretamente el formato `wav`. Solo tienes que indicar la ruta donde se encuentra tu fichero de sonido y si quieres que se repita continuadamente o no.

**El código:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Sound 
{
    public void sound()
    {       
        try{
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("src/Sonidos/fondo.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();
            sonido.open(audio);
            sonido.start();
            sonido.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); //repetir siempre
        }catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex){System.out.println("Error");}
    }
}
```

Espero que pueda servirte! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener 2 causas que impiden la reproducción:

1) La ruta del archivo es incorrecta.

2) Suponiendo que la ruta es correcta, el problema principal es aquí, elimina el `while`, ya que posiblemente no se puede determinar el valor de isRunning() :

```
  ...
  //while (sonido.isRunning())
        Thread.sleep(1000);
  ...
```

---

Código correcto:

```
       // Se obtiene un Clip de sonido
        Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();

        // Se carga con un fichero wav
        sonido.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\adric\\Desktop\\ejemplo.wav")));

        // Comienza la reproducción
        sonido.start();

        // Espera mientras se esté reproduciendo.            
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        // Se cierra el clip.
        sonido.close();
```